# Android P2P direct connection for multiple devices. Peer as GroupOwner and client at the same time

Tags: android, p2p, wifi-direct, wifip2p, mesh-network

I want to create a chat application (without internet connection) for Android-based on P2P communication via WI-FI (or Bluetooth) between 3 or more devices. I would like every device to have a direct connection to all devices. I know that android API provides the WifiP2pGroup class, but in this case, one device is a groupOwner and the other are clients and the other ones do not have a direct connection with each other.

Is it possible for each device to be a groupOwner and client for other devices at the same time (like on the image)? Is there another way to solve my problem?

[image]

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you may check Bluetooth Bridgefy app used by Hong Kong protesters last time - they even have their SDK.

Comment: I'm not wifi direct expert, but I couldn't find anything in the docs that forbids multiple groups and clients, https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct